# Fill in the most recent value highest value in the row field over the date column using tableau or sql

Tags: sql, tableau-desktop

I have a data having 0,1,2 values in the row field and dates in increasing order in the column field and I would like the last '2' value keep constant moving forward in the dates. Please do let know a way to workaround. Example may 2027 has 2 and then 0 but I would like to have 2 in june 2027 and the rest of the dates.I would like to keep previousor beginning date values same but has the maximum value 2 in this case carry forward to the later dates.

Thank you.

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0Blj.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

MS SQL Syntax:

```
SELECT TOP 1 value FROM YourTableName WHERE value <> 0 ORDER BY date_action DESC
```

MySQL Syntax:

```
SELECT value FROM YourTableName WHERE value <> 0 ORDER BY date_action DESC LIMIT 1
```